# Set environment variables then run script in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shell-script, groovy, environment-variables

I am new to Jenkins, Groovy and pipelines. I have created a simple pipeline stage like so:

```java
//working build but not setting env variables
node('build-01') {
    stage('Building') {
        echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.BUILD_ID}) on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
        try {
            sh 'ls -l'
            //ls shows the damn file
            sh '. setup-target'
        } catch(all) { 
            sh "echo 'Failed to run setup-target script with error: ' ${all}"
        }
    }    
}
```

This works. But I want to modify/add environment variables to the session running this script (this script is a bash file with the correct shebang line on top). So I did:

```java
node('build-01') {
    withEnv(["CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}", "SDK_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}"]){
        stage('Building') {
            echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.BUILD_ID}) on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            try {
                sh 'ls -l'
                //ls shows the damn file
                sh '. setup-target'
            } catch(all) { 
                sh "echo 'Failed to run setup-target script with error: ' ${all}"
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

This errors out with:

> > /home/jenkins-sw/ci/workspace/myWorkSpace@tmp/durable-6d30b48d/script.sh: line 1: .: setup-target: file not found

and

> > Failed to run setup-target script with error:  hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1

But the environment variables are set, I check this by doing a `sh 'printenv'` right below the `ls -l` line. Interestingly `ls -l` does show the script.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was cloning directly into the workspace and then setting my environment variables to point to the workspace as well. I modified both those things. I now create a dir in my workspace and clone into it and I also set my environment variables to directories inside my workspace. Like so:

```
node('build-01') {
    withEnv(["CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}/cmake_install", "SDK_INSTALL_DIR=${WORKSPACE}/sdk"]){
        stage('Building') {
            echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.BUILD_ID}) on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            try {
                sh 'ls -l'
                //ls shows the damn file
                dir('path/to/checkout') {
                    sh '. ./setup-target'
                }
            } catch(all) { 
                sh "echo 'Failed to run setup-target script with error: ' ${all}"
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

This works.

Note: Since this site is in beta phase and I barely got any views I posted the same question to stackoverflow, here it is for refernce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015463/set-environment-variables-then-run-script-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline